# Get output with flag if same record comes next time in informatica power center

Tags: compare, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to put flag if records again comes from source in informatica power center
This need to achieve in informatica power center. After that I will use filter transformation to pass only flag =1 records to output. Basically I need to track changed record of flag and load as scd 2 in target table.

```
Input
Number        Code     Date
1234          3        2022/01/22
1234          3        2022/01/23
1234          4        2022/01/24
1234          3        2022/01/25
1234          3        2022/01/26
1234          2        2022/01/27
1234          4        2022/01/28
4567          1        2022/01/29
4567          1        2022/01/20
4567          3        2022/01/21

Output
Number        Code     Date             Flag
1234          3        2022/01/22         1
1234          3        2022/01/23         2
1234          4        2022/01/24         1
1234          3        2022/01/25         1
1234          3        2022/01/26         2
1234          2        2022/01/27         1
4567          1        2022/01/29         1
4567          1        2022/01/20         2
4567          3        2022/01/21         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use variable ports in an expression transformation to track values in the previous record and set a flag depending on whether a value has changed or not.

Because Informatica evaluates variable ports in order, if the variable port that compares the current record (input port) with the previous record (variable port x) is before variable port x, variable port x will hold the value from the previous record.

There are plenty of detailed examples of this common pattern if you google for them e.g. this [one](https://www.folkstalk.com/2013/12/get-previous-row-value-in-informatica.html)

Comment: But here I need add flags by comparing with previous record. Can you suggest that one please

Comment: That’s what I did suggest(and linked to an example of). What, precisely, do you still need help with?

Comment: It is not working in my case, I searched so many links and it is now working